# Can I create one ad in Google Adsense and then copy and paste the code on more then one page?

Tags: google, advertising, google-adsense

And if I do, will it effect how much money the ads make in any way? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can copy and paste the ad code on other pages. That code is really determining the size of the ad and your publisher ID so you get paid. It will not affect how much money the ad makes.